# Animate a custom drawable

Tags: java, android, animation

I built a type of chatting app, and I want to make my own animated emoji, I have good experience on cinema 4d and I can design/animate anything.

I know that I can make my special animated emoji several different ways, like creating it as a gif, a transparent video, multiple pictures and then run it with a timer, etc.

What would be the best way to animate [my Emoji](https://s11.postimg.org/qo9wy69kz/eagle_image.jpg)?

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to work in android is with vector drawables. JPEGs are not a recommended format in android, as PNGs are preferred. Check [the official guide](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html) on animations and drawables for further reference.